# Did I solve this particle problem correctly?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

So, I'm supposed to find the equation for the velocity of the particle and the equation for the position of the particle.

I was given the acceleration, which is $-21\, \frac{\rm ft}{\rm s^2}$.
I was also given the initial velocity and distance, which are $4\, \frac {\rm ft}{\rm s}$ and $14\, {\rm ft}$.

So, what I did was this:

I integrate $a(t)$ to get $v(t) = -21t + C$, substituted $4$ for $t$ $(0=-21(4)+C)$ to get $C = 84$.

So, for velocity I got $v(t) = -21t + 84$.

Then, I had to solve for $s(t)$, so I integrated to get
$$
s(t) = \frac{-21t^2}{2} + 84t + C.
$$

I substituted $14$ for $t$ $(0 = \frac{-21(14)^2}{2} + 84(14) + C)$ to get $C = 882$.

So, for the position equation I got
$$
s(t) = \frac{-21t^2}{2} + 84t + 882.
$$

Did I do this correctly?

Comment: Correct method for the most part, but you plugged in your initial conditions backwards: an initial velocity of $4$ feet per second means $v(0) = 4,$ not $v(4) = 0.$

Answer (score 0):

The acceleration of the particle is
$$
a(t) = {d^2 x \over dt^2} = - 21 \ {\mbox{ft} \over s^2}
$$

Integrating, we get
$$
v(t) = {dx \over dt} = - 21 t + c_1
$$
where $c_1 is an integration constant.

Given that initial velocity is $4$ ft / sec.

Hence,
$$
v(0) = 4 \ \implies \ c_1 = 4
$$

Hence,
$$
v(t) = {dx \over dt} = - 21 t + 4 \ \ \ {\mbox{ft} \over s}
$$

Integrating again, we get the position of the article as
$$
x(t) = - {21 t^2 \over 2} + 4 t + c_2
$$
where $c_2$ is an integration constant.

Given that initial position is 14 ft.

Thus,
$$
x(0) = 14 \ \implies \ c_2 = 14
$$

Hence, the position of the particle is
$$
\boxed{x(t) = - {21 t^2 \over 2} + 4 t + 14}
$$